# Compiler complains about redefinition even with guards present

Tags: c++, namespaces, glfw, redefinition

I'm trying to set up some logging functions for an OpenGL application. GLFW offers the option to register a callback function that is called whenever an error takes place, but because it is a C library it demands that the function be written in C style, i.e. outside of a class. Because of that, I put my logging functions into a namespace defined in file `log.h`.

```
#ifndef LOG_H
#define LOG_H

#include <fstream>

namespace gllog{    
  #define GL_LOG_FILE "gl.log"
  bool restart_gl_log(){
    //...
  }

  bool gl_log (const char* message, const char* filename, int line){
    //...
  }

  void glfw_error_callback (int error, const char* description){
    //...
  }  
};
#endif
```

Even though I added include guards, whenever I include this file from two different files, I get errors like the following:

```
CMakeFiles/gl4tuts.dir/extended_initialisation/ExtendedInitialisation.cpp.o: In function `gllog::glfw_error_callback(int, char const*)':
ExtendedInitialisation.cpp:(.text+0x340): multiple definition of `gllog::glfw_error_callback(int, char const*)'
CMakeFiles/gl4tuts.dir/hello_triangle/HelloTriangle.cpp.o:HelloTriangle.cpp:(.text+0xa10): first defined here
```

I'm building with CMake.

What could be the reason? Could the absence of a class be related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include guards protect you from including the same header file more than once while compiling the same `.cpp` file. They don't stop you from including the same header file more than once while compiling different `.cpp` files -- in fact they're commonly used to make the same class available in different compilation units.

The compiler is not complaining, by the way, the linker is.

Comment: But shouldn't they stop whatever is in the #ifndef block from being defined twice? (which seems to be the problem here).

Comment: In the same compilation unit, yes. But you have more than one compilation unit. (If they were only included in one, how would the other even know the types those functions take?)

Comment: Then why is it that I can include other header files in more than one file? I just did the exact same thing with another file that contains a class instead of a namespace and it works fine.

Comment: To my last comment I should add that using a class seems to be irrelevant. It works with a namespace as well so there must be something wrong with the file in which I'm writing my log functions.

Comment: @broncoAbierto The other header files don't contain code that creates multiple definitions. Yours does. (Do you now understand why your code creates a definition of `glfw_error_callback` in every compilation unit that includes it? Look at the other headers that work and see that they don't do that.) If not [start here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Comment: Ok, I see my mistake now. Even if I'm using some C-style code I still should keep the declarations in the header file and the definitions in the cpp file. Thanks.